# Which place is claimed by the most countries?

Tags: international-law, territorial-dispute

According to the Times Comprehensive Atlas of the World, fifteenth edition 2018,. the Spratly Islands in the South China Sea are claimed by Brunei, China (PRC), Malaysia, Philippines, Taiwan (ROC), and Vietnam.  That's six countries.  Is that a record?  What territory is clamed by the most countries?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a trivia question; [Wikipedia:List of territorial disputes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes) seems to contain a comprehensive answer

Comment: @bytebuster trivia questions shouldnt be closed unless they have an answer elswhere on the internet.

Comment: @EkadhSingh: it looks like the OP voted to close their own question... And so did you...

Comment: @Fizz this one had an answer elsewhere on the internet, as shown by bytebusters comment

Answer (score 5):

> Which place is claimed by the most countries?

[Antarctica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_claims_in_Antarctica) with seven.

> Seven sovereign states have made territorial claims in Antarctica, which are Argentina, Australia, Chile, France, New Zealand, Norway and the United Kingdom.

There are three [Overlapping claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_claims_in_Antarctica#Overlapping_claims),

- Argentina and United Kingdom
- Argentina,  Chile, and United Kingdom
- Chile and United Kingdom

There are [possible future claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_claims_in_Antarctica#Possible_future_claims) by as many as six countries, of which, some overlap.

- United States
- Russia
- Brazil (overlap with Argentina and United Kingdom)
- Peru
- Uruguay
- Ecuador (overlap with Chile and Norway)

Comment: Does it count if they aren't overlapping claims?  Or do all seven actually claim the same pieces of land?

Comment: @Bobson - There are [Overlapping claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_claims_in_Antarctica#Overlapping_claims); but, whether this is an answer depends on the meaning of "territory." Also, unlike the Spratly Islands, no country claims all of Antarctica. Like Antarctica, there are countries that claim only parts of the Spratly Islands.

Comment: If they aren't all overlapping and none claim all of it, then how can you say that 7 countries claim Antarctica? How would it be any different to say the answer is 'Africa', since 50-ish countries have claims there, with [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes#Africa) more overlaps than Antarctica?

Comment: @Giter - I chose Antarctica because it is similar to the Spratly Islands -- no inhabitants except for some outposts. I rejected the entirely of the inhabited continents. I had considered that there may have been more than 100 indigenous peoples' nations with disputed claims on North America. Finally, if the only answer could be the Spratly Islands, then the answer to the question would not have been very interesting.

Comment: I thought Antartica's claims were rather well-behaved, with treaties and whatnot basically committing everyone to good behavior.  That's rather different in nature, even if technically correct, than the OP's reference to a hot dispute like the Spratleys (or Kashmir) where war is not entirely to be ruled out.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - I was not always peaceful. _See_, Antarctic Treaty System, [International conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Treaty_System#International_conflicts).